# F# pipe first parameter

Tags: parameters, f#, pipe, currying

is that possible to pipe the first parameter into a multiple parameter function?
for example

```
date = "20160301"
```

Is that possible to pipe `date` into

```
DateTime.ParseExact(    , "yyyyMMDD", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @yuyoyuppe explains in [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35716893/126014), you can't pipe directly into `ParseExact` because it's a method, and thereby not curried.

It's often a good option to define a curried Adapter function, but you can also pipe into an anonymous function if you only need it locally:

```
let res =
    date |> (fun d -> DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

which gives you a `DateTime` value:

```
> res;;
val it : DateTime = 01.03.2016 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 8):

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx):

> Methods usually use the tuple form of passing arguments. This achieves
>   a clearer result from the perspective of other .NET languages because
>   the tuple form matches the way arguments are passed in .NET methods.

Since you cannot curry a function which accepts tuple directly, you'll have to wrap the `ParseExact` to do that:

```
let parseExact date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMDD", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Perhaps unrelated, but output arguments can be bound like that:

```
let success, value = Double.TryParse("2.5")
```

Note that `TryParse` accepts the tuple with the second argument as `byref`.